# I have a problem with my rinkeby faucet reagarding testnets?

Tags: blockchain

I want to get some free testnets from  [**Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet**](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) but every time i do the whole process and pastes my link i got this message pop up.

[image]

Kindly tell me what should i do. OR there any good alternatives through which i can get the free testnets. I'm currently started learning Block-Chain, so i don't know much.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com is for asking about stackexchange network itself. See for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110852/where-can-you-ask-about-career-advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/ you can get something like 0.1 Eth

https://rinkeby-faucet.com/ gives you 0.001

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the links, really appreciate. I went to this site  https://www.rinkebyfaucet.com/ . If you sign up to it, if you sign up to it will give you 0.5 testnets once per day.

Comment: Ali Hassan that's good then, which means they increased from 0.1

Comment: Leereal no they don't increased from 0.1. Without sign up on the site they give 0.1 eth once per day but after you sign up you can get 0.5 once per day. Hope you understand.

Comment: Oh okay yes I understood